# How to pipe output from external process in Rack

Tags: ruby, rack

In a nutshell, I want to make an on-the-fly thumbnail script. All I want to do is run ImageMagick on an existing image file and pipe the output back to the web client. I somehow can't quite figure out the syntax.

I already know the ImageMagick command:

```
/usr/bin/convert /path/to/my/image.png -resize 64x64 -
```

Easy peasy. Now, if that command is run in the call() method of the Rack application, what do I return to output the resulting image?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand. Does your Imagemagick command line work or not? If not, then try

```
/usr/bin/convert /path/to/my/image.png -resize 64x64 PNG:-
```

Sorry, I do not know Rack.

Comment: The command line works just fine. What I don't know how to do is pipe the output to Rack.

Comment: Why not just use RMagick rather than Imagemagick command line. That way it is all in Ruby.

Comment: RMagick sounds great! But I've looked at the docs and just can't figure out how to do what I need. Can you provide a simple example of simply resizing an image and sending something back from call() so that Unicorn can send out the image?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know RMagick.